# how i design model when have 2 relationships between 2 tables in code first entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

i have to entity {person , child} each person have many child , and a child it self is a person , we have to relationship here , one to one between child and person and another relationship one to many between person and child

```
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("person")]
    public int IDperson { get; set; }
    public virtual Person person { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("parent")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public int IDparent { get; set; }
    public virtual Person parent { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLength(50)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public String name { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IList<Child> children { get; set; }
}
```

i write these for relationships, is this ok ?

Comment: Why don't you let Child extend from Person? Then you can remove the person relationship

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen suggested, inheritance might be useful in your scenario:

```
public class Child : Person
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("parent")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public int IDparent { get; set; }
    public virtual Person parent { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLength(50)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public String name { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IList<Child> children { get; set; }
}
```